# Programmatically resend the IT policy to a BlackBerry from the BES

Tags: blackberry

Is it possible to resend the IT policy to a blackberry from the associated BES programmatically (and how)?

The functionality I am trying to achieve is the same as what is accomplished with the 'Resent IT policy to a device' in the BES administration service web app. I have tried to use the BES User Administration Client (called from my application) to achieve this functionality but it is not supported for BES 5.x, what I want to know is whether it is possible via the BlackBerry Administration API to achieve this? To clarify, I want to initiate the resend of the policy from my application running on the BES, not from an application on the blackbery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this via the BlackBerry Webservices for Enterprise Administration API (details in my forum thread [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Enterprise-Server/Resend-IT-policies-from-BES-programmatically-via-API-or-similar/m-p/2122513#M1314)), it is possible to achieve the resending of the policy to the device via this API call

```java
public void sample() {
   SetUsersResendITPolicyRequest request = new SetUsersResendITPolicyRequest();
   request.setMetadata(metadata);
   //"user" was returned from getUsers() API
   request.getUsers().add(user);

   SetUsersResendITPolicyResponse response = bws.setUsersResendITPolicy(request);

   if (response.getReturnStatus().getCode().compareTo("SUCCESS") != 0) {    
       System.out.println("Error occurred: " + response.getReturnStatus().getMessage());
   }
}
```

as detailed [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/bws/enterprise/admin/5.0.4.35/com/rim/ws/enterprise/admin/BWS.html#setUsersResendITPolicy%28com.rim.ws.enterprise.admin.SetUsersResendITPolicyRequest%29). This works in Java or .net as the API is supported for both.